# Se a classe ofstream é para escrever em arquivos, ifstream para ler e fstream para os dois casos, por que não usar sempre fstream de uma vez?

Tags: c++, classes, arquivo, stream

Mesmo se quiséssemos ler, escrever, modificar, criar, deletar arquivos, ou outras operações, já não poderia utilizar a classe `fstream`? Que problemas poderiam gerar se não usar aquelas específicas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fstream` serve para ler e escrever em arquivos (pode até criar se não existir), não serve para deletar arquivos.

Em condições normais não há problema algum nisso, pode usar. Algumas pessoas preferem deixar mais claro o que está fazendo em cada caso quando só faz uma das operações.

É possível inclusive configurar o `fstream` em cada momento para só aceitar leitura ou só aceitar escrita, assim evita cometer erros, portanto até nisso é igual, desde que se use isso. Mas não é tão semântico quanto os objetos preparados só para cada uma das operações, e não será detectado problemas na compilação quando tenta escrever em algo que só queria ler e vice-versa.

Pode ser que alguma implementação específica dê alguma vantagem interna de usar um ou outro, mas aí caímos em detalhe que não pode ser respondido de forma geral para toda linguagem, tem que ver a documentação da implementação para saber se tem alguma diferente entre usar um ou outro. O contrato e forma de usar é igual, e até o resultado, mas como se chega nesse resultado por mudar um pouco. Mas seria mais sensato que seja igual, estou falando apenas de possibilidade.